# How can i use percent symbol in c# variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to write variable for my health counter system,but i dont know why it making red the-; , how can i write % symbol in variable?

```
int Heart = 100%;
int Heart2 = 20%;
```

Comment: What datatype do you want your variable to be? Integer or string?

Comment: TBQH, your question doesn't even make sense. It sounds like you need to read about [C# data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types). If that's too technical an introduction, search for something about strongly typed vs. weakly typed languages. C# is strongly typed.

Comment: basically, you want a visual representation change and you are trying to change the data itself. you should transform the data type to a string for display and then you can add the percent sign.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string, if you will not edit these values.
Or you can just use double (1,0.2) and at the output multiply by 100 + "%";.

```
double hearth = 1;
double hearth2 = 0.2;

Console.WriteLine(hearth * 100 + "%");
Console.WriteLine(hearth2 * 100 + "%");
```

Comment: Or with help of *string interpolation*: `Console.WriteLine($"{hearth * 100}%");`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko or actually why not use the correct formatter right away and do `Console.WriteLine($"{hearth:P2}");` ? ;) => `0.123` -> `12.30 %`